# Vue: Pinia state property doesn't update in component with node-forge

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, spinner, csr, pinia

I read the other stackoverflow questions but does not help. I use `pinia=2.0.27`. I could extend the example if neccessary.

I have a component with a button with a spinner.

```
<template>
  ....
  <button
    type="submit"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    :disabled="loading ? true : false"
    @click="submitForm"
  >
    <span
      v-show="loading"
      class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"
      role="status"
      aria-hidden="true"
    />
    <span v-show="loading"> Wait </span>
    <span v-show="!loading">
      Create certificate
    </span>
  </button>
  ....
</template>
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { useUserStore } from "@/store/UserStore";

const { loading } = storeToRefs(useUserStore());
</script>
<script>
export default {
  async submitForm() {
    try {
      await useUserStore().createCertificate();
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the pinia store:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import forge from "node-forge";

export const useUserStore = defineStore({
  id: "UserStore",
  state: () => {
    return {
      loading: false,
    };
  },
  actions: {
     async createCertificate() {
       this.loading = true;
       try {
         const keys = forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(2048);
       } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
       } finally {
         this.loading = false;
       }
    },
  },
});
```

The problem is, that the `doStuff` function already runs and the `loading` property is still false inside the component and the spinner is very late visible.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was misleading, so I deleted it. One thing I can think of is the separate script tag with another `useUserStore()`. Maybe this is causing some issues with the `loading` ref. AFAIK you can define the async function in the setup script as well. Or use the when/then syntax:

Comment: @Thomas: I tried to use the setup function, but doesn't help. I think the problem is node-forge.